# Can Netbeans 8.1 and 8.2 coexist?

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I want to port a Java Windows app developed in NetBeans 8.2 to Android. Problem is, the nbandroid plugin supports NetBeans only up to 8.1.

Can I install 8.1 on the same Windows machine, so I can use it for my Android work continue using 8.2 on my other projects?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  I have both installed on my machine.  They use their own install directory.